# Libraries for distributed-memory Cholesky factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, parallel-computing, c, mpi

What libraries can compute dense Cholesky factorizations in distributed-memory environments (preferably using [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)). I'm using C/C++, and have access to a cluster of between 1 and 40 nodes, where each node has 12 cores. I've heard of [ScaLAPACK](http://netlib.org/scalapack) but am interested in alternatives.

Comment: I guess you've also heard of Trilinos [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997436/libraries-for-parallel-distributed-cholesky-decomposition-in-c-c-in-mpi-enviro) ;) Have you tried it?

Comment: [Cough](http://elemental.googlecode.com/files/using-elem.pdf)

Comment: @JackPoulson:  Coooolllll :-)  Checking now :-)  Looks a little more modern than scalapack, hopefully doesn't involve spending hours learning how to handle Fortran compilation, and learning obscure 6-letter function names :-D

Comment: (@JackPoulson: note that the CMakeLists.txt file in hg requires cmake 2.8.8; I manually changed it to 2.8.5, so that it would build on Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: @JackPoulson: just to check, if I'm using OpenBLAS, which is multithreaded, do I need to explicitly call `openblas_set_num_threads(1)` when I'm using Elemental?

Comment: The short answer is yes, but we should probably take the long answer elsewhere. Feel free to email elemental-dev@googlegroups.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In alphabetical order (**disclaimer**: I am the main author of [Elemental](http://code.google.com/p/elemental)):

### DPLASMA

[Distributed Parallel Linear Algebra Software for Multicore Architectures (DPLASMA)](http://icl.eecs.utk.edu/dplasma/) is a relatively recent and ongoing effort by [Bosilca](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/~bosilca/) et al. to extend [PLASMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/plasma/index.html) to distributed-memory machines. [Version 1.0.0](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/parsec/custom/index.html?lid=145&slid=256) supports distributed Cholesky factorizations, among many other operations. DPLASMA is written in C and uses MPI. Their website links to the following [handout from SC12](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/graphics/posters/files/SC12-DPLASMA-PaRSEC.pdf), though there has been significant progress since then. This is the only software in the list which currently makes use of [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)-scheduling, and it appears to have begun development around 2010.

### Elemental

[Elemental](http://code.google.com/p/elemental) is a modern retake and extension of many of the ideas behind [PLAPACK](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~plapack) and [ScaLAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack) (described below). It is written in C++ and currently sits on top of [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas), [LAPACK](http://netlib.org/lapack), and [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). Please see [this recent presentation](https://elemental.googlecode.com/files/using-elem.pdf) for a more detailed overview and some short example programs. Development began around 2009 and is still picking up steam. Contrary to PLAPACK and ScaLAPACK, its characteristic communication pattern is [allgather](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Allgather.html).

### PLAPACK

[Parallel Linear Algebra PACKage (PLAPACK)](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~plapack) was developed from around 1997-2000 and introduced the idea of providing an easy means (in the sense of just calling a routine named *Copy*) of redistributing (sub)matrices from one distribution to another. [The main author of PLAPACK](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~rvdg) has actively contributed to Elemental's development. PLAPACK was written with C and MPI, it sits on top of BLAS and LAPACK, and its characteristic communication pattern is [broadcast](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Bcast.html).

### ScaLAPACK

[Scalable Linear Algebra PACKage (ScaLAPACK)](http://netlib.org/scalapack) has been under development since about 1995 and is thus the earliest (and also most commonly used) of the bunch. ScaLAPACK is primarily written in Fortran, but several of its routines are written in C, and most of its communication is performed in terms of the [Basic Linear Algebra Communication Subprograms](http://netlib.org/blacs), which is (now) typically implemented using MPI. It was purposely designed so that its high-level code resembles that of LAPACK, and the local computations that occur are typically calls to BLAS and LAPACK. The characteristic communication pattern in ScaLAPACK is [broadcast](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Bcast.html).